# How to use tabs on setup composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I define `tabs` as `prop`, then I want to use in function inside `setup()` as `tabs.value...`, but it does not recognize property. It is throwing error:

> Cannot find name 'tabs', tabs is not defined

Code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import {
  defineComponent,
  ref,
  computed,
  PropType,
  toRefs,
} from '@vue/composition-api'
import i18n from '@/setup/i18n'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ProgramModal',

  props: {
    tabs: Array as PropType<Array<any>>,
  },

  setup() {
 
    const changeTab = (selectedTab: { id: number }) => {
      tabs.value.map((t) => {
        t.id === selectedTab.id ? (t.current = true) : (t.current = false)
      })
    }

    return {
      tabs,
      changeTab,
      ariaLabel,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

How can I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `props` to `setup` function:

```
setup(props) {...
```

Comment: Excelent, now I can return it using `props.tabs?`, is there any way to remove possible undefined in tabs declaration, it says:  Prop tabs requires default value to be set?

Comment: Make the prop to be a required one.

Comment: Awesome, it works using:   `tabs: { type: Array as PropType<Array<any>>, required: true,},` Thanks!